# How to test my app on my device without Ionic serve

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m new to ionic and i just finished my first app and it work perfectly on my browser, but I just wanna know how to run it on my android device without the need of ‘ionic serve’ being launched on my PC, I mean my app currently works on my mobile but only if I run ‘ionic serve’ on my pc is there any way to make it run without the need of that. Or I’m missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/deploying/#android-devices)** :

> To run your app, all you have to do is enable USB debugging and Developer Mode on your Android device, then run `ionic cordova run android --device` from the command line.
>
> This will produce a debug build of your app, both in terms of Android and Ionic’s code
>
> Enabling USB debugging and Developer Mode can vary between devices, but is easy to look up with a Google search. You can also check out **[Enabling On-device Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options)** in the Android docs.

When you think your app is ready to be released, please take a look at the *Production Builds* and *Sign Android APK* sections also from **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/deploying/#android-devices)**.